# How to get all Gsuite account applications from Google directory API?

Tags: google-workspace, google-directory-api, google-gsuite

I want to get all G-suite application list that user has access.

There is an API to fetch all third party application that user has access.
API reference https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens

But we want SAML application list as well as google apps like google voice.

We can get all events for that application but there is no api to fetch only application list
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list.

Could any one help me to get all application list?